# Is a graph determined up to isomorphism by its path category?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, directed-graphs

This is probably easy and/or well known, but I couldn't find anything with my brain or with google.

Let $G$ be a directed graph.  Recall that the *path category* of $G$ is is the category whose objects are vertices of $G$ and whose morphisms are finite sequences $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ where the target of each $e_i$ is the source of each $e_{i+1}$.  (Composition of morphisms corresponds to appending sequences.)

My question is:

> Is there a pair of non-isomorphic graphs with equivalent path categories?

If the answer is "no", then I have a follow-up:

> Suppose two graphs have equivalent path categories.  Is every equivalence induced by an isomorphism of graphs?

Answer (score 4):

The path category is the free category on a graph, and this free functor is not fully faithful, since a functor between path categories need not preserve the arrows coming from the underlying graph (it is faithful but not full.)

However, the free category functor is conservative, and even reflects equivalences into isomorphisms, as you request. The reason has to do with the structure theory of free categories. They are exactly those categories with a class $\mathcal I$ of indecomposable arrows-the word is used literally, for those arrows inexpressible as a nontrivial composition-such that every arrow is uniquely a composition of arrows from $\mathcal I$. Now, it's easy to see that indecomposability is preserved by isomorphisms of categories, so that ann isomorphism of free categories restricts to a bijection on objects and on indecomposable arrows, that is, to ann isomorphism of the underlying graphs.

Seen another way, the free category functor *is* fully faithful as a functor into the subcategory of categories with functors which preserve indecomposables, and this subcategory contains all isomorphisms.

Now, we're really interested in *equivalences* of free categories, and equivalences need not preserve indecomposability: consider the projection of the category generated by two isomorphic objects to the terminal category. However, the isomorphism category is not free, and an equivalence of free categories actually *does* yield an isomorphism on underlying graphs, simply because free categories are skeletal-there are no nontrivial isomorphisms-so that every equivalence between them is actually an isomorphism!

Answer (score 2):

*Every Equivalence of path-categories is induced by an isomorphism of graphs:*

Throughout, let $G$ and $H$ be graphs. Denote by $\mathrm{P}(G)$ and $\mathrm{P}(H)$ the respective free (path-) categories, for which we fix the following construction:

***Definition of the Path-Category:***
Objects of $\mathrm{P}(G)$ are the vertices of $G$, morphisms are strings of edges $(e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n)$ where composition is given by concatenation of paths

$$(e_1,\dots,e_n) \circ (e'_{1},\dots,e'_{n'}) = (e_1,\dots,e_n,e'_1,\dots e'_{n'})$$

and identities are given by the empty path, which we denote by $(\,)$. (leaving the object implicit)

***Lemma 1:*** If $f \in \mathrm{P}(G)$ is an isomorphism, it is an identity already.

***Proof:*** By definition $f$ is some path $f = (e_1,\dots e_n)$. And so is its inverse $f^{-1} = (e'_1,\dots, e'_n)$. We must have:

$$(e_1,\dots,e_n) \circ (e'_1,\dots,e'_{n'}) = (e_1,\dots,e_n,e'_1,\dots,e'_{n'}) = (\,)$$

Which can only be satisfied if $f = (\,)$. $\square$

***Corollary:*** If a functor $F: \mathrm{P}(G) \rightarrow \mathrm{P}(H)$ is an equivalence of categories, then $F$ is an isomorphism of categories.

***Lemma 2:*** An isomorphism  $F:\mathrm{P}(G) \rightarrow \mathrm{P}(H)$ sends paths of length 1 to paths of length 1.

***Proof:*** Let $e$ be an edge in $G$. Let $F^{-1}$ be the inverse of $F$. Let $$F(e) = (d_1,\dots,d_n)$$
be the path in $H$. Since $F^{-1}$ respects composition we must have
$$F^{-1}((d_1,\dots,d_n)) = (F^{-1}(d_1),\dots, F^{-1}(d_n) )=(e)$$
Which again, can only be satisfied if $(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ is a path of length $1$. $\square$

***Corollary:*** If $F: \mathrm{P}(G) \rightarrow \mathrm{P}(H)$ is an equivalence of categories between the path-categories of graphs, then $F$ is induced by an isomorphism of graphs $G\cong H$

***Proof:*** The corresponding morphism of graphs is simply $F$ restricted to objects for the map on vertices and $F$ restricted to paths of length 1 for the map on edges, which is well-defined by Lemma 2 and an isomorphism by the previous corollary. $\square$